# How to pass the coordinate in MKAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, annotations, maps, coordinate

File .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface mappa : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

File .m

```
#import "mappa.h"

@interface mappa ()

@end

@implementation mappa

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    MKPointAnnotation * myAnnotation1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    myAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.000000, 7.000000);
    myAnnotation1.title = @"Example one";
    myAnnotation1.subtitle = @"Best one";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];

    MKPointAnnotation * myAnnotation2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    myAnnotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(46.000000, 8.000000);
    myAnnotation2.title = @"Example one";
    myAnnotation2.subtitle = @"Best two";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation2];

}





-(void)mapView:
                (MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:
                                                    (MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
                                                                                    (UIControl *)control
{


    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=46.000000,8.000000&daddr=Example one"];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];



}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{



    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    //if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
      //  return nil;

    // Handle any custom annotations.
   if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puntatore.png"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);

            // Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;



            // Add an image to the left callout.
            //UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"puntatore.png"]];
            //pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = iconView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;

}



- (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    float spanX = 0.00725;
    float spanY = 0.00725;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

How can I have two different buttons that lead to two different links with the corresponding coordinates? So why take all those with the same class and brings them to the same link for the direction of the maps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your zoomToCurrentLocation method works, first refactor it to something like this:

```
-(void) zoomToLatitude: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)lat
             longitude: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)lon
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    float spanX = 0.00725;
    float spanY = 0.00725;

    region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;

    region.center.latitude = lon;
    region.center.longitude = lat;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self zoomToLatitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude
               longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Put the buttons in your interface, hook them to two different IBAction -methods. And call

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction: (id)sender
{
    [self zoomToLatitude: <latitude here>
               longitude: <longitude here>];
}
```

Comment: No I want different link for each annotation...

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=46.000000,8.000000&daddr=Example one"];

and other for other annotation...

Comment: OK. Make your view controller as MKMapViewDelegate and implement -mapView:didSelectAnnotationView: . With that you know which annotation view is selected and can do whatever you wish to do.

Comment: but how do I pass the coordinates to the function: (void)mapView: (MKMapView *)mapView annotationView: (MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped ??

Comment: In calloutAccessoryControlTapped, the annotation is available using view.annotation and the coordinates using view.annotation.coordinate.

Comment: If I add "NSString*coord=view.annotation.coordinate;" not working... where I must add?

Comment: @user3565647, The coordinate property is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D (not an NSString *).